# Do XeLaTeX have the same file extension as LaTeX files?

Tags: xetex

As far as I know LaTeX files have the extension `.tex`. Does that apply to XeLaTeX as well?

Comment: You can use whatever extension you like, as long as there's one. No current implementation of TeX engines allows files without extension. If you run an engine over a file name without extension, `.tex` is automatically added. But `pdflatex foo.baz` or `xelatex baz.foo` are good as well.

Comment: Thank you. I was just curious what extension is used in general for xelatex.

Comment: @egreg extensionless files work fine for me with all texlive engines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

egreg basically answered your question in the comments, but I believe *most* people use the `.tex` extension for both, especially as most documents designed for (pdf)latex can also be compiled with xelatex. You can feel free to use a `.xelatex` or `.xltx` extension or similar for your own convenience to keep track of the difference, but if you'll want your tooling programs to treat them differently, you'll have to manually configure them to do so.